# Media wiki AWC forum

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am using a forum extension in mediawiki called [AWC forum](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAWC%27s_Forum)

I need to get a summary of the today' posts on daily basis through email.

Can anyone suggest how should be the structure of the php for this?

Answer (score 0):

I once thought of using it, but I used the [Disqus Widget](http://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/DISQUS) instead. You can handle everything from there, but I do not know if that covers what you aim to do.